# Como não ordenar automaticamente IN(MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Executo este comando SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id
IN (144,140,134,133,128,129,141,143,149,150,147,146,126,142,125,99,100,92,91,90,108,109,123,124,122,121,110,89) 
ORDER BY none
```

Porém a consulta vem com as *IDs* ordenadas, como impedir isso?

Comment: E que ordem você gostaria de aplicar?

Comment: a ordem que especifiquei no in..

Comment: Tente assim usando o [`Field`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field): `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id in(144,140,134,133,128,129,141,143,149,150,147,146,126,142,125,99,100,92,91,90,108,109,123,124,122,121,110,89) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 144,140,134,133,128,129,141,143,149,150,147,146,126,142,125,99,100,92,91,90,108,109,123,124,122,121,110,89);`

Comment: Acredito que a resposta aqui pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O resultado de um `SELECT` é ordenado através das definições de INDEX na sua tabela. Por exemplo, se a sua tabela possui a coluna *id* como PRIMARY KEY, [ela será um INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html) da sua tabela automaticamente, embora seja possível definir outras.

Ao invés de não-ordenação, o que você quer é uma ordenação personalizada.
Se eu estiver correto, você consegue esse efeito usando a função [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id IN (144, 140, 134, ...)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 144, 140, 134, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode-se utilizar a [função `FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

> **FIELD**(*str,str1,str2,str3,...*)
>
> Retorna o índice (posição) de `str` na *str1*, *str2*, *str3*,... *lista*. Retorna *0* se `str` não for encontrada.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 4, 2, 1, 3);
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a015be/1)

O teu comando SQL fica assim:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos 
WHERE id IN 
(144,140,134,133,128,129,141,143,149,150,147,146,126,142,125,99,100,92,91,90,108,109,123,124,122,121,110,89) 
ORDER BY FIELD 
(id, 144,140,134,133,128,129,141,143,149,150,147,146,126,142,125,99,100,92,91,90,108,109,123,124,122,121,110,89);
```